# php parsing json using value from list

Tags: php, json

I have a json like this:

```
"achievementsProgress": [
    {
      "value": 11,
      "globalID": 23000000
    },
    {
      "value": 11,
      "globalID": 23000001
    },
    {
      "value": 11,
      "globalID": 23000002
    },
    {
      "value": 147,
      "globalID": 23000003
    },
    {
      "value": 147,
      "globalID": 23000004
    },
    {
      "value": 147,
      "globalID": 23000005
    },
    .....
]
```

It goes on like that and I need to be able to read the `"value"` field of every 3rd.

So `globalID` `23000002`, `23000005`, `23000008`, `230000011` etc. All the way up to and including 65. And then I need to save those as variable names like:

`$achievement1` for `globalID` `23000002`
`$achievement2` for `globalID` `23000005`

etc.

Now I assume this has to be done in a loop.

So far I have this much.

```
$jsondata = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true)
```

and it would be

`$data['achievementsProgress']` to get to the list of the above json.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Why do you want to make all these variables? It seems like you _may_ be making things more difficult for yourself than necessary.

Comment: nope @Don'tPanic this is necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. I think any way you'll be able to do this will need to involve [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

```
$x = 1; // start a counter for your variable names
for ($i=2; $i < 65; $i+=3) { // start at index 2 (3rd value) and increment by 3
    if (isset($data['achievementsProgress'][$i])) {  // just in case there aren't actually 65
        // Use variable variables to create the $achievement variables you want
        ${"achievement$x"} = $data['achievementsProgress'][$i]['value'];
    }
    $x++;
}
```

This example uses [complex string syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) to create the variable variable.

Comment: I can't seem to be able to get this working... I used that script and then tried `"echo $achievement1";` but it didn't show anything...

Comment: Sorry, that's probably because I used object notation in the answer. I missed that you had used json_decode with the associative option.

Comment: @ShivamPaw I updated the answer to use array syntax instead.

Comment: Thanks ;) That's working now. Just suggested an edit to fix a minor mistake which was probably cuz the question was unclear :)

Comment: @ShivamPaw Accepted. It _was_ clear, I just used that key when I tested it to make sure it was getting the right one and then forgot to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Better do it like this:

```
$jsondata = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
$items=$data->achievementsProgress;
$result=[];
$i=1;
foreach($items as $item)
   if($i++%3==0)
       $result[$item->globalID]=$item->value;
//now $result contains map of data you wanted globalid => value
```

Now you can access it like this:

```
$result['23000000'] == 11 and so on
```

Comment: $data['achievementsProgress'] was named incorrect. now it should work

Comment: still not working. I am using json_decode with the associative option.